# Can I make this kind of radio button?

Tags: javascript, button, text, acrobat

Essentially I want have 2 options on button click with a group of 3 buttons.

Buttons can say: Free or Qtr

And if one button says qtr then the other buttons in that group must say free

This is the closest script that has worked properly but it is for colored checks, not for text and also doesn’t offer the radio function of making it say free if qtr is selected on another button in group

```
     if(color.equal(event.target.textColor,color.black))
 event.target.textColor = color.green;
```

else if(color.equal(event.target.textColor,color.green))
event.target.textColor = color.red;
else
event.target.textColor = color.black;